# Weird stage behaviour while parallel call is present

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

There are some stages in my pipeline that may fail by themselves but not fail the build process. I wanted this stages to be indicated as failed so a wrapped them in `try`-`catch` blocks. However some of the stages kept showing as successful while in reality being failed. After some research I was able to pinpoint the problem: all of the 'wrong-displaying' stages had `parallel` calls in them (the effect takes place even if blocks in `parallel` do absolutely nothing).

In the end I was able to boil down the problem to this minimal reproducible example:

```java
node {
    try {
        stage("A") {
            error "E"
        }
    } catch(e) {}
    
    try {
        stage("B") {
            parallel a : {}, b : {}
            error "E"
        }
    } catch(e) {}
}
```

Here the `A` stage will show up as failed and `B` stage will show up as successful. Swapping them will yield the same result (`A` failed; `B` successful). Changing `error "E"` to `throw new Exception("E")` does not make any difference. In both cases exception is being thrown and caught without any problems, only stage appearance is affected.

After that I tried executing more than one of the stages similar to `B` and it turns out that each stage initially shows up as successful (even though it is failed). When the following stage finishes it also shows up as successful but at the same time the previous one starts showing up as failed. When the third stage finishes, the second changes to failed, and so on until the last stage. Last stage stays successful since there is no next stage to "update" it. Logically this can be countered by inserting a dummy `parallel` call after the last stage in chain:

```js
...
parallel foo : {}
...
```

The question is: what is going on with `parallel`? Am I using it wrong or is it some kind of bug?

Important note: I'm using Jenkins 2.150.2 without an ability to move to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I think idea behind the `parallel` must be about having dedicated stage without any other steps before or after. This design is well visible in declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("A"){
            steps{
                catchError( stageResult: 'FAILURE'){
                    error "E"
                }
            }
        }
        stage("B") {
            parallel {
                stage("p1") {
                     steps{
                         catchError( stageResult: 'FAILURE'){
                         error "a"
                         }
                     }
                }
                stage("p2") {
                      steps{
                         catchError( stageResult: 'FAILURE'){
                          echo "b"
                         }
                      }
                }
            }
            //echo "test1" // illegal
        }
        stage("C"){
            steps{
                error "E"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you try to put anything after parallel there will be syntax error.
So to answer the question: you must be using unpredicted step sequence and so you are getting strange results.
Still, the results are strange only for STAGE VIEW plugin as I can see in my Jenkins instance. So you have green rectangle for failing stage but whole job status is FAILED as it should be actually.

Coming back to your scripted example:

```
node {
        stage("A") {
            catchError(stageResult: 'FAILURE'){
            error "E"
            }
        }
        stage("B") {
            catchError( stageResult: 'FAILURE'){
            parallel a : {stage("p1"){error "a"}}, b : {stage("p2"){echo "b"}}
            }
        }
        stage("C"){
            error "E"
        }
}
```

It is much cleaner to use `catchError` step.
To put anything after parallel you should use separate stage for that purpose.
If you reserve separate stage for parallel you will get consistent Jenkins behavior.

Comment: I know about `catchError`, however as I stated I'm stuck with Jenkins 2.150.2 so I can't use it. Thanks for the answer anyway, I'll give it a try